# conditional and interventional expectation

Tags: regression, experiment-design, causality, conditional-expectation

Conditional expectation $E[Y|X]$ and interventional expectation $E[Y|do(X)]$ are related but conceptually very different things.

I know that if $X$ is a randomly assigned by an experiment, we have that 
$E[Y|X]=E[Y|do(X)]$
In some other case we can achieve the equivalence by conditioning on proper *set of variables* $Z$:  $E[Y|X,Z]=E[Y|do(X)]$

My question:
is possible to consider both $X$ and $Z$ as vector  of variable**s**?
Usually in an experiment we are focused in just one causal variable ($X$ as scalar), however logically seems me that the generalization is permitted.

Comment: Definitely. There is a literature on causal interaction, which concerns two treatments (i.e., $X$s). [VanderWeele (2009)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25662776) is a decent paper on this issue. There is also a literature on sequential treatments and mediation, which consider the outcomes were one to experimental intervene on a sequence of treatments. [VanderWeele (2009)](https://insights.ovid.com/crossref?an=00001648-200901000-00006) (different paper) is another decent paper on this issue. Note these use potential outcomes, which are similar to `do(x)` operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can consider $X$ and $Z$ to be arbitrary vectors of variables. The identification problem of expressions of the type $E[Y|do(X)]$ and $E[Y|do(X), Z]$ for arbitrary vectors of variables $X$ and $Z$ [has been solved for nonparametric models using the do-calculus (via the ID-algorithm).](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/shpitser08a/shpitser08a.pdf)

For instance, in the model below, suppose you are interested in identifying $E[Y|do(X_1, X_2)]$:

[image]

This is given by (here you can just use the truncated factorization formula):

$$
E[Y|do(X_1, X_2)] = \sum_{Z_1, Z_2} P(Y|X_1, X_2, Z_2) P(Z_2|X_1,Z_1) P(Z_1)
$$

Or equivalently, using inverse probability weights:

$$
E[Y|do(X_1, X_2)] = \sum_{Z_1, Z_2} \frac{P(Y, X_1, X_2, Z_1, Z_2)}{P(X_2|X_1, Z_1, Z_2)P(X_1|Z_1)} 
$$

The [R package causaleffect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/causaleffect/index.html) has several of the existing identification algorithms implemented.

Comment: I know that the backdoor criterion permit us to find several sets $Z$ that permit to identify the ACE of $X$ on $Y$; then $E[Y|X,Z]=E[Y|do(X)]$. Now, backdoor criterion is applicable even if $X$ is a vector?

Comment: If the SCM in your example was a linear system, what regression I have to compute in practice for identify $E[Y|do(X_1,X_2)]$? In other words, what regression is associated with the first equation you wrote if any?